# Configure gradle.build to build all spring boot sub projects to jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have multi-module Gradle project. Each module is full application with own `@SpringBootApplication`. Root project has no sources in src. How to configure root/build.gradle to build all sub-modules to executable JARs on executing `./gradlew build` command from root directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom task in your `root` module that will execute `build` task for all submodules :

```
task buildAll() {
    subprojects.forEach {
        buildAll.dependsOn it.tasks.getByName('build')
    }
}
```

and then invoke it :

```
./gradlew buildAll
```

This way every submodule will be build and boot jar will be available in the `build/libs` directory of every submodule. Also you can name this task `build` - it all depends on your current configuration.